# CQ5 - Separate out a servlet's business logic into a standalone bundle

Tags: aem, osgi-bundle

I am new to java, osgi, bundles, cq5 console etc..

Can someone please point me to a tutorial or a starting point from where I can learn how to do what I am trying to achieve.

Basically we have common search functionality in 3-4 CQ5 websites, all of which reside on a single cq instance. This same functionality is implemented in all websites as a servlet and is called from client side using javascript. Redundant code....
We would like to: 
a) take this servlet's code out from all the websiteName-core bundles where it resides repeatedly as of now. 
b) create a single separate standalone installable OSGI bundle which only contains a servlet. 
Then we would like to call this single separated out bundle from all our CQ5 websites's client side.

Aprt from code redundancy, we wish to make this common search bundle shippable so that other development teams can use it in their projects by just installing it in their console and calling the servlet.

Long story short. I want to create an OSGI bundle that has a servlet.

I wish to have an understanding of the whole game here and would prefer to get a tutorial link that explains it from start to end.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by turning the search code into a separate maven multi module project.The archetype and instructions for creating one can be found on adobe's documentation site ([link](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/aem-how-tos/development/how-to-build-aem-projects-using-apache-maven.html))

The maven multimodule project will have two module's Bundle and content. Bundle will hold all the servlets, OSGI services and back-end stuff. The content module will have all the UI and authoring related stuff like templates and components. It maps to the repository on the CQ server. The UI nodes are serialized and stored on flat file systems as XML documents.

Since it is a maven project on it's own, it's dependencies will be self contained. In the bundle module add the search servlet and all the required classes. The compiled package of this project will be shippable.

As long as the package is installed in the server, any other website will be able to make calls to it.

Servlets in sling are implemented as OSGI services of `javax.servlet.Servlet` class. Any exported service of the Servlet class will be recognized by the sling servlet resolver, You can get more details of it at this [link](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sharath Madappa's answer is correct if you want to create a set of related bundles and distribute them as a CQ content package.

If you just want to create a single bundle to package some OSGi services (including servlets) you just need to build the bundle jar with the required metadata. The [Apache Sling GET servlets bundle](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/bundles/servlets/get) is a good example of that.